# Object() is not a function when building a PrivateRoute for my React Router-equipped app

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Basically, I have an app where you can see movies (their title, poster, date, actors, summary etc.) and if you're logged in, add one. It doesn't use APIs for getting that list of movies so everything is done with Redux store. So I searched online for a PrivateRoute component that would allow me to redirect the user to the login page (for example, if I was logged in, tested something in my Adding movie component and changed something then reloaded the app, my app would still remain on that add movie page even though I'm not logged in).

Here's my PrivateRouter (PublicRouter right after)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import isLogin from '../utils/isLogin';

const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    return (

        // Show the component only when the user is logged in
        // Otherwise, redirect the user to /signin page
        <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            isLogin() ?
                <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to="/login" />
        )} />
    );
};

export default PrivateRoute;

import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import isLogin from '../utils/isLogin';

const PublicRoute = ({component: Component, restricted, ...rest}) => {
    return (
        // restricted = false meaning public route
        // restricted = true meaning restricted route
        <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            isLogin() && restricted ?
                <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
            : <Component {...props} />
        )} />
    );
};

export default PublicRoute;
```

and my App.js with the routes:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/Routes/Home'
import About from './components/Routes/About'
import Login from './components/Routes/Login'
import Navbar from './components/navbar/Navbar'
import Movie from './components/Movie'
import Addon from './components/Routes/Addon'
import PublicRoute from './components/Routes/PublicRoute'
import PrivateRoute from './components/Routes/PrivateRoute'

class App extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div className='the-app'>
                    <Navbar />
                    <Switch>
                        <PublicRoute restricted={false} exact path='/' component={Home}></PublicRoute>
                        <Route path='/about' component={About}></Route>
                        <PublicRoute restricted={true} path='/login' component={Login}></PublicRoute>
                        <PrivateRoute path='/add' component={Addon}></PrivateRoute>
                        <Route path='/:movie_id' component={Movie} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

the isLogin() logic function (I'm connecting it to the store since I have a isLoggedIn boolean there):

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const isLogin = () => {
    if(this.props.user.isLoggedIn) {
        return true;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        user: state.user
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(isLogin)
```

I'm not sure exactly what the cause is. It compiles fine and looks like a usual React component/function.

EDIT: I fixed the error. It doesn't show Object() not a function anymore...but the ProtectedRoute thing won't work.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import isLogin from '../utils/isLogin';

const PublicRoute = ({component: Component, restricted, ...rest}) => {
    return (
        // restricted = false meaning public route
        // restricted = true meaning restricted route
        <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            isLogin && restricted ?
                <Redirect to="/login" />
            : <Component {...props} />
        )} />
    );
};

export default PublicRoute;
```

Private:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import isLogin from '../utils/isLogin';

const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    return (

        // Show the component only when the user is logged in
        // Otherwise, redirect the user to /signin page
        <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            isLogin ?
                <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to="/login" />
        )} />
    );
    
};  

export default PrivateRoute
```

Router:

```
<Router>
                <div className='the-app'>
                    <Navbar />
                    <Switch>
                        <PublicRoute restricted={false} exact path='/' component={Home}></PublicRoute>
                        <Route path='/about' component={About}></Route>
                        <PublicRoute restricted={false} path='/login' component={Login}></PublicRoute>
                        <PrivateRoute path='/add' component={Addon}></PrivateRoute>
                        <Route path='/:movie_id' component={Movie} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
```

Comment: isLogin function will return undefined if expected to get false, which in your case won't matter

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props => {
      return isLogin() && restricted ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/login",
            state: { from: props.location },
          }}
        />
      );
    }}
  />
);
```

Comment: You forgot about restricted ) Thx